# Trouble with getting xauth access token from Twitter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with using creepymap.py

I try to get it to authorize Twitter account.. but I get error message:

```
/usr/share/creepy $ python creepymap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "creepymap.py", line 515, in button_authorize_twitter
    url = self.oauth.get_authorization_url(True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/auth.py", line 103, in get_authorization_url
    raise TweepError(e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Ive looked in auth.py and I try to follow the code with the comments for example:

```
def get_authorization_url(self, signin_with_twitter=False):
        """Get the authorization URL to redirect the user"""
        try:
            # get the request token
            self.request_token = self._get_request_token()

            # build auth request and return as url
            if signin_with_twitter:
                url = self._get_oauth_url('authenticate')
            else:
                url = self._get_oauth_url('authorize')
            request = oauth.OAuthRequest.from_token_and_callback(
                token=self.request_token, http_url=url
            )
```

later on I read this:

```
def get_xauth_access_token(self, username, password):
    """
    Get an access token from an username and password combination.
    In order to get this working you need to create an app at
    http://twitter.com/apps, after that send a mail to api@twitter.com
    and request activation of xAuth for it.
    """
    try:
        url = self._get_oauth_url('access_token', secure=True) # must use HTTPS
        request = oauth.OAuthRequest.from_consumer_and_token(
            oauth_consumer=self._consumer,
            http_method='POST', http_url=url,
            parameters = {
                'x_auth_mode': 'client_auth',
                'x_auth_username': username,
                'x_auth_password': password
            }
        )
```

is there anything I should change in the code?

P.S Sorry for my english. It is not my native language.

Thank you!

EDIT: 
I just wanted to close thread with answering my own question after some more research..

And follow instructions here on how get xAuth: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth

Comment: I know nothing about [creepy](http://ilektrojohn.github.io/creepy/), but from the error message it looks like you are unable to authenticate.  Are you sure your password and username are correct?